# Find the repartition function of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory, functions

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable, and $X :\begin{pmatrix}0&1&2\\\frac15&\frac25&\frac25\end{pmatrix} $. Then it's repartition function will be:

$F_{X}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}0\;\;,\;x\;\;<\;0\\\frac15,\;0\;\leq x<1\\\frac25,\;1\;\leq\;x<\;2\\1,\;x\;\geq\;2\end{array}\right.$

Why aren't we considering the last probability value? Or is it just because it happens to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an error in that I think the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)=\frac35$ for $1 \le x \lt 2$ rather than your $\frac25$

So you could say

$$F_{X}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}0\;,&\;x\;\;<\;0\\\frac15,&\;0\;\leq x<1\\ \frac15+\frac25,&\;1\;\leq\;x<\;2\\\frac15+\frac25+\frac25,&\;x\;\geq\;2\end{array}\right.$$

and you are cumulating all three probability values

Comment: Yeah that was $\frac 35$, sorry about that, oh now I see, thank you!